# Printing lists on the same line using stdout

Tags: python, list, binary-tree, stdout, sys

I'm trying to get the output of BST using stdout instead of print. The issue is when the stdout displays the values seem to get jumbled up.

I've tried doing things such as `sys.stdout.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in str(node.data)))`. And `sys.stdout.write(str(node.data))`. Code Below.

```
import sys


class Node:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


# function to convert sorted array to a
# balanced BST
# input : sorted array of integers
# output: root node of balanced BST
def sort_array_to_bst(arr):
    if not arr:
        return None

    # find middle
    mid = (len(arr)) / 2
    mid = int(mid)

    # make the middle element the root
    root = Node(arr[mid])

    # left subtree of root has all
    # values <arr[mid]
    root.left = sort_array_to_bst(arr[:mid])

    # right subtree of root has all
    # values >arr[mid]
    root.right = sort_array_to_bst(arr[mid + 1:])
    return root


# A utility function to print the preorder
# traversal of the BST
def pre_order(node):
    if not node:
        return

    #sys.stdout.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in str(node.data)))
    # Output : 5 71 5 78 9 83 9 72 61 7 86 7 9
    #sys.stdout.write(str(node.data))
    # Output: 5715789839726178679
    #print(node.data, end=" ")
    pre_order(node.left)
    pre_order(node.right)


arr = [7, 898, 157, 397, 57, 178, 26, 679]
root = sort_array_to_bst(arr[1:])
pre_order(root)
```

The output is expected to be `57 157 898 397 26 178 679`.

But as commented out in the code for `sys.stdout.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in str(node.data)))`, I get the output `5 71 5 78 9 83 9 72 61 7 86 7 9`

And for `sys.stdout.write(str(node.data))`, I get the output `5715789839726178679`.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `' '.join()` on the `str(node.data)`, which means it will take `57` and join a space between every char of `57`. Just try replacing the stdout with `sys.stdout.write(str(node.data) + ' ')` within the `pre_order()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should not convert `node.data` to a string before you iterate through it; otherwise you would be iterating over the individual characters of the string.

Change:

```
sys.stdout.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in str(node.data)))
```

to:

```
sys.stdout.write(' '.join(str(x) for x in node.data))
```